# HTML Form  filtering with populated drop down

Tags: list, html

Just want some help knowing the best way to perform the following.

I have a HTML Form web part that is filtering a list below it and all is working OK, but what we would like to do is have the contents of the drop down be populated from a column on the list.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using SharePoint web services, use 2 ajax call - first one to populate the dropdown and based on that selection get data for that particular row, you have the data now you can use anything for ui, design it as you wish.

For SharePoint service help you may refer my previous [comment](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43577/jquery-and-javascript-can-i-get-the-last-id-from-document-library/43586#43586) in another thread. Please ask for more clarification or code snippet if you have any question.